# The program works, but when a player inputs a location it doesn't show up on the board. What can I do to fix this?

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void CreateCharBoard(int Board[][3], char CharBoard[][3]);
void PrintBoard(char CharBoard[][3]);
bool CheckWinner(int Board[][3], int Player);
void ResetBoard(int Board[][3]);
bool CheckMove(int Board[][3], int Row, int Column);

int main(){
    // delcare and initialize (if necessary) all required variables here
    int Board[3][3];
    char CharBoard[3][3];
    int Player, Row, Column;
    bool Win = false;
    char Again = 'y';
    // Print lab header and if desired, statement of what this lab is doing
    //this line of code will pause the program until the user hits any key to continue
    system("pause");

    while (Again == 'y'){
        ResetBoard(Board);
        system("clear");
        while (Win == false){
            CreateCharBoard(Board, CharBoard);
            PrintBoard(CharBoard);
            cout << "Player O's turn!" << endl;
            cout << "Enter row number: "; cin >> Row;
            cout << "Enter column number: "; cin >> Column;
            CheckMove(Board, Row, Column);
            //update board
            Win = CheckWinner(Board, -1);
            if (CheckWinner (Board, -1)  == true){
                cout << "Player O wins!" << endl;
                break;
            }
            //set flag to denote it's x's turn
            PrintBoard(CharBoard);
            cout << "Player X's turn!" << endl;
            cout << "Enter row number: "; cin >> Row;
            cout << "Enter column number: "; cin >> Column;
            CheckMove(Board, Row, Column);
            //update board
            Win = CheckWinner (Board, 1);
            if (CheckWinner (Board, 1) == true){
                cout << "Player X wins!" << endl;
                break;
            }
            }

            cout << endl << endl;
            cout << "Would you like to play again? (y/n): ";
            cin >> Again;
            }

            cout << endl << endl;
            cout << "Good bye!" << endl;

            return 0;
            }

            // function to take game board and create a board with corresponding characters
            void CreateCharBoard(int Board[][3], char CharBoard[][3])
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                        // if game board has a -1, put an "O" in the character board
                        if (Board[i][j]== -1){
                            CharBoard[i][j] = 'O';
                        }
                        // if game board has a 1, put an "X" in the character board
                        else if (Board[i][j]== 1){
                            CharBoard[i][j] = 'X';
                        }
                        // if game board has a 0, put an " " (blank space) in the character board
                        else{
                            CharBoard[i][j] = ' ';
                        }
                    }
                }  
            }
            // print the character representation of the game board
            void PrintBoard(char CharBoard[][3]){
                cout << "  Tic Tac Toe!" << endl << endl;
                cout << "    0     1     2" << endl << endl;
                cout << "0    " << CharBoard[0][0] << "  |  " << CharBoard[0][1] << "  |  " << CharBoard[0][2] << endl;
                cout << "   -----------------" << endl;
                cout << "1    " << CharBoard[1][0] << "  |  " << CharBoard[1][1] << "  |  " << CharBoard[1][2] << endl;
                cout << "   -----------------" << endl;
                cout << "2    " << CharBoard[2][0] << "  |  " << CharBoard[2][1] << "  |  " << CharBoard[2][2] << endl << endl;
            }
            // function to check if a player, either "X" or "O" has won the game
            bool CheckWinner(int Board[][3], int Player){
                int Sum;
                // check each column
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                    Sum = Board[i][0] + Board[i][1] + Board[i][2];
                    // if O is a winner
                    if (Sum == 3*Player){
                        return true;
                    }      
                }
                // check each row
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                    Sum = Board[0][j] + Board[1][j] + Board[2][j];
                    // if O is a winner
                    if (Sum == 3*Player){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                // check diagonal
                Sum = Board[0][0] + Board[1][1] + Board[2][2];
                if (Sum == 3*Player){
                    return true;
                }
                Sum = Board[0][2] + Board[1][1] + Board[2][0];
                if (Sum == 3*Player){
                    return true;
                }
                // if none of the rows, columns, or diagonals = 3*player, then return false
                return false;
            }
            // function to reset all elements of the game board back to 0
            void ResetBoard(int Board[][3]){
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                        Board[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }  
            }
            // function to see if player's move is valid, if 0 (or not played) return true, otherwise false
            bool CheckMove(int Board[][3], int Row, int Column){
                if ((Row < 0) || (Row > 2)){
                    return false;
                }
                else if ((Column < 0) || (Column > 2)){
                    return false;
                }
                else if (Board[Row][Column] == 0){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: `while (Win == false)` etc. is bad style. Please use `while (!Win)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you newer update your `Board`.

The only line where you write anything into `Board` is in `ResetBoard()` where you reset all values to `0`.

In your game-loop are two lines `// update board` - I suppose you forgot to implement the function for that...

Other flaws:

- You call `CheckWinner` twice - once to set `Win` and once for the check, if user has won.
- The return of `CheckMove` is not used - there should be an loop that reads input till the player enters valid data.
- If one player has won you end the `while`-loop by break. The check `while (Win == false)` is never used and to show that to everybody it should be `while(true)`.